# Ferramenta de backup

Tags: banco-de-dados, servidor, amazon-aws, backup, software

Utilizo os serviços da AWS e tem me atendido muito bem, porém há um tempo atrás acabei ficando com o serviço indisponível por alguns dias, o que acabou complicando algumas tarefas que precisava acessar que estavam no servidor.
Resolvi então que ter um backup seria fundamental para tais tarefas posteriormente.

Gostaria de ver com vocês se me recomendam alguma ferramenta de backup para este assunto?

Comment: está utilizando o rds?

Comment: Estou sim @Danizavtz.

Comment: No rds existe um serviço integrado de backup. Basta você configurar. Se acessar o painel do rds ele possui o nome: `Backups automatizados`

Comment: Muito obrigado @Danizavtz, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre isso.